# How can I fix an Integrity constraint violation about 'linked_product_id' (when importing)

Tags: debugging, ee-1.13.0.1, importexport

During import I get errors like

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 
    'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or 
    update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails   
    (`foo`.`catalog_product_link`, CONSTRAINT 
    `FK_CAT_PRD_LNK_LNKED_PRD_ID_CAT_PRD_ENTT_ENTT_ID` FOREIGN KEY 
    (`linked_product_id`) REFERENCES `catalog_product_entity` (`entity_id`)' 
    in lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228
```

I already changed `Mage_ImportExport_Model_Import_Entity_Product::_saveLinks()` for debugging the single inserts:

```
        if ($linkRows) {
            foreach($linkRows as $row) {
                $adapter->insertOnDuplicate(
                    $mainTable,
                    $row,
                    array('link_id')
                );
            }
```

And now I get `linked_product_id' cannot be null'`

The full import stops because of this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add some debug code in `\Mage_ImportExport_Model_Import_Entity_Product::_saveLinks` to track down this problem and to avoid, that the full import stops:

```
    if ((isset($this->_newSku[$linkedSku]) || isset($this->_oldSku[$linkedSku]))
            && $linkedSku != $sku) {
        if (isset($this->_newSku[$linkedSku])) {
            $linkedId = $this->_newSku[$linkedSku]['entity_id'];
        } else {
            $linkedId = $this->_oldSku[$linkedSku]['entity_id'];
        }
        $linkKey = "{$productId}-{$linkedId}-{$linkId}";


// [BEGIN CHANGE] - Comment: Debug
        if ($linkedId == null) {
            Mage::logException(
                new Exception(
                    sprintf('Debug - WARNING: Orphaned link skipped: From SKU %s (ID %d) to SKU %s, Link type id: %d',
                        $sku, $productId, $linkedSku, $linkId)
                )
            );
            continue;
        }
// [END]
```

This will log an exception with detailed information about the products and links the error is about.

*In my case there were errors with the products referenced as related products. So those products were skipped during import and Magento generated links to "null"*

[Magento 2 PullRequest](https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/324)